# How to set action on real time

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have code on server and I want the code to be executed at a certain time

I used datetime but it is not working in my code

```
import datetime
current_date_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
current_time = current_date_time.time()

async def autopost():
    if current_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S') == '20:27:30':
        print(current_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Hello UnfixingMite500,
With so few informations it's difficult to help you, but 3 elements seem to be checked :
1) In your exemple you set the "current_time" once, be sure the "current_time" is regulary updated or it will keep the value you affect to it initialy.
2) In your exemple you never call "autopost" or await for it, be sure in your real application the function is called and awaited for
3) If you want your function to run Maybe you should use the >= operator instead of the ==. The == will work only if the code line is interpreted during the specified second, not the second after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code that needs to be run at a particular time, you should configure a cron job, for linux and if I remember correctly in windows the equivalent is scheduled tasks.